# Add nested property in Redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been a few days trying to get my head around Redux to be used with my Reactjs project. I'm working on a reducer and trying to add a nested property into state. To do this, I'm using spread operator at different levels. The problem is that initially the state slice this reducer manages is empty and therefore I run into the following problem... taking this as an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
var foo = {}; // Initially the state slice is an empty object.

var bar = {...foo,
            1: {
                ...foo[1],
                2: {
                    ...foo[1][2],
                    baz: 100 // New property I'm trying to add.
                }
            }
};

console.log(bar);
```

(property keys 1 and 2 are two variables provided to the reducer in my actual app)

I you run the above piece of code it will yield en error saying `Cannot read property '2' of undefined` at line `...foo[1][2],`. Alright, `foo[1][2]` is not defined yet, but how am I supposed to accomplish this? Maybe I'm missing something very basic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that works for your example but it seems pretty hacky.

```
bar = {
  ...foo,
   1: {    
     ...foo[1] ? foo[1] : {},

     2: {
       ...foo[1] && foo[1][2] ? foo[1][2] : {},
       baz: 100 // New property I'm trying to add.
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great @Damien Dall'agnola! that will do the trick but still have the doubt: isn't my example a common scenario that most programmers run into when state is empty? how is this achieved in redux normally?... Am I doing something incorrect or not following best practices with reducers or state shape?

Comment: i guess i would change the state shape, but it's hard to know how without a concrete exemple of the state.
like the 1 and 2 property, are they static?

Comment: 1 and 2 keys are variables that I provide to the reducer through the action. 1 and 2 are just random keys, it could be any value.

Comment: the problem is the nesting because you have to check each step if the inner object already exists, you could flatten your key for exemple "1.2" or any character that isn't in your property